# Adjective to describe someone in a very good mood

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

> A cheerful/high-spirited Jeff came up to the bar.

Which adjective would be the best suited in the above sentence to describe that Jeff seems in a very good mood?

Would "cheerful" or "high-spirited" work? If either of them are okay, which one would you prefer in the context?

Comment: `Delighted`, `sprightly` ? Just google it(cheerful) you'll get a lot.

Comment: An [**elated**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/elated) Jeff came up to the bar. The context given is minimal – it depends on who is speaking, and the kind of language they would use.

Comment: Ebullient. (fill characters)